# How can I generate RTF file in laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel-5, phpword

I want to generate and save .rtf file in laravel 5.2. I can generate PDF file. But I can not find any solution for RTF. Can anyone tell me Is there any library or package to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [RTF by Jack Clayton](https://github.com/jstewmc/rtf)? It's fairly old but may still work.